# The train leaves in the morning, and arriving at Jinju. (Is this sentence right?)

Tags: grammar, participle-phrases

> The train leaves in the morning, and arriving at Jinju.

Some people think the "and" should be removed.

What's the truth?

Comment: I'm not sure "ungrammatical" is the right term for what's wrong ***after*** removing the completely incorrect "and", but ***arriving*** isn't the right kind of verb here. It's a ***semantic*** problem, in that the adverbial participial clause after the comma must refer back to the train ***at the time when it leaves***. It cant be ***simultaneously arriving*** somewhere else, so that optional additional participial clause needs to be changed to ***destined / heading** for Jinju* or similar. OR change it to *The train leaves in the morning, and **will be** arriving at Jinju [at some time].*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the sentence is ungrammatical with the "and."

It should be

> The train leaves in the morning, arriving at Jinju.

Comment: Or "...and arrives at Jinju at [time]."